# Button Input using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm creating BattleShip in Python 3.4.1 and I'm using Tkinter.

This is my source code:

```
from tkinter import *

vText = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]

def press(a,b):
    print("You pressed: " + str(a * 10 + b))

root = Tk()

def button():
    for i in range(0,10):
        global self
        for j in range(1,11):
            self = Button(root, text = vText[i] + str(j), command = lambda: press(i,j), padx = 20, pady = 20).grid(row = i, column = j)
    root.wm_title("Enemy grid")
button()
root.mainloop()
```

Later I want to do a function based on what button is pressed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `press` function to accept an additional parameter.

```
def press(a, b, text):
    print("You pressed: " + str(a * 10 + b), text)
```

And pass the button text to the function:

```
Button(root, text = vText[i] + str(j),
       command=lambda i=i, j=j, text=vText[i] + str(j): press(i, j, text),
       padx=20, pady=20).grid(row=i, column=j)
```

NOTE: use of keyword argument in `lambda` to bind the current value of `i`, `j`. If you don't use keyword argument, `i`, `j`, .. will reference the last values that was assigned in the loop.

BTW, `grid` returns nothing (= return `None`). Assigning the return value to a variable does not have meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, it didn't seem to work. I don't understand the comma in the print statement. Was that a typo or something? Relatively new to python, but when I used your code it had errors galore.

Comment: Also, I am aware that i and j reference the last values. Any way to stop that?

Comment: @3.14-Thon, `, text` is there to print `text` passed.

Comment: When I ran that, it didn't work... Specifically, it reported that "text is not defined"

Comment: @3.14-Thon, I think you didn't change the signature of the function `press`. Try this (full code): http://pastebin.com/nnHLvdLM

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! That works perfectly. Must have been something that I did wrong. Awesome.